# How to push back the button on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I start to learn javascript from [W3scholl](http://www.w3schools.com). I wanna make the push button from this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst):

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to clear the date text after I push the button again, how to do this?

Comment: I assume by saying "push" you mean to "Click" button. your code seems correct to me.. do you got any error ? just set innerHTML="" to clear the text

Comment: You say you want to learn, and link to a tutorial called "My First JavaScript".  It's good that you want to immediately start tinkering, but perhaps you should continue through more tutorials before jumping into questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code writing service

Comment: @Magisch, it's a question of educational purpose, not imho for misuse SO as coding service.

Comment: @NinaScholz "I want to do $behavior, how do I do this in code?" Is basicly "Please write code for me that does $behavior and explain it to me" paraphrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a global variable `state` and save the last changed state.

Click on button calls `toggle` and the function evaluates `state` for the next action. At the end of the function `state` changes with the [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)).

```js
function toggle() {
    if (state) { // check state
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('button1').innerHTML = 'Click me to display Date and Time.'
    } else {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date();
        document.getElementById('button1').innerHTML = 'Delete Date and Time.'
    }
    state = !state; // toggle state
}

var state; // undefined, becomes later true and false
```

```html
<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="toggle()">Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new button like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
 Click me to display Date and Time.
</button>

<button type="button" onclick="Empty()">
 Click me to delete Date and Time.
</button>

<script>
function Empty(){
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```